# killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

I'm try to insert data into the externaltable
running hadoop in GCP.
 I created external table and
 trying to insert data into external table

```
   hive> insert overwrite table vgsale4es select * from vgsale4;

   Query ID = saivarunakuraju_20190829134803_eceef196-1695-4ad5-90e0-46580ca9c9a5
   Total jobs = 1
   Launching Job 1 out of 1
   Tez session was closed. Reopening...
   Session re-established.
   Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1567078294077_0006)
```

why only map vertices is running and not reduce is not

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      MODE        STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1            container       RUNNING      1          0        0        1       4       0  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 00/01  [>>--------------------------] 0%    ELAPSED TIME: 450.23 s   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Status: Failed
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1567078294077_0006_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1567078294077_0006_1_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1567078294077_0006_1_00_000000_0:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:185)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:86)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[10.168.0.3:9200]] 
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:152)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:424)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:388)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:392)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:168)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.request.GetAliasesRequestBuilder.execute(GetAliasesRequestBuilder.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:622)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.init(EsOutputFormat.java:175)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsHiveOutputFormat$EsHiveRecordWriter.write(EsHiveOutputFormat.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:547)
    ... 18 more
], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1567078294077_0006_1_00_000000_1:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:185)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:86)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[10.168.0.3:9200]] 
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:152)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:424)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:388)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:392)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:168)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.request.GetAliasesRequestBuilder.execute(GetAliasesRequestBuilder.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:622)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.init(EsOutputFormat.java:175)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsHiveOutputFormat$EsHiveRecordWriter.write(EsHiveOutputFormat.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:547)
    ... 18 more
], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1567078294077_0006_1_00_000000_2:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:185)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:86)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[10.168.0.3:9200]] 
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:152)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:424)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:388)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:392)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:168)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.request.GetAliasesRequestBuilder.execute(GetAliasesRequestBuilder.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:622)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.init(EsOutputFormat.java:175)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsHiveOutputFormat$EsHiveRecordWriter.write(EsHiveOutputFormat.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:547)
    ... 18 more
], TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1567078294077_0006_1_00_000000_3:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:185)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:86)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[10.168.0.3:9200]] 
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:152)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:424)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:388)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:392)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:168)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.request.GetAliasesRequestBuilder.execute(GetAliasesRequestBuilder.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:622)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.init(EsOutputFormat.java:175)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsHiveOutputFormat$EsHiveRecordWriter.write(EsHiveOutputFormat.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)

]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:0, Vertex vertex_1567078294077_0006_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]
DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:0
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1567078294077_0006_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1567078294077_0006_1_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1567078294077_0006_1_00_000000_0:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:185)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:86)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[10.168.0.3:9200]] 
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:152)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:424)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:388)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:392)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:168)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.request.GetAliasesRequestBuilder.execute(GetAliasesRequestBuilder.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:622)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.init(EsOutputFormat.java:175)
    at MapOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:547)
    ... 18 more
], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1567078294077_0006_1_00_000000_1:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:185)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:86)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[10.168.0.3:9200]] 
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:152)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:424)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:388)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:392)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:168)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.request.GetAliasesRequestBuilder.execute(GetAliasesRequestBuilder.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:622)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.init(EsOutputFormat.java:175)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsHiveOutputFormat$EsHiveRecordWriter.write(EsHiveOutputFormat.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:547)
    ... 18 more
], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1567078294077_0006_1_00_000000_2:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rank":"Rank","name":"Name","platform":"Platform","year":"Year","genre":"Genre","publisher":"Publisher","na_sales":"NA_Sales","eu_sales":"EU_Sales","jp_sales":"JP_Sales","other_sales":"Other_Sales","global_sales":"Global_Sales"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:86)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[10.168.0.3:9200]] 
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:152)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:424)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:388)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:392)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:168)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.request.GetAliasesRequestBuilder.execute(GetAliasesRequestBuilder.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:622)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.init(EsOutputFormat.java:175)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsHiveOutputFormat$EsHiveRecordWriter.write(EsHiveOutputFormat.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:547)
    ... 18 more
]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:0, Vertex vertex_1567078294077_0006_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:0
```

Only Map container is running why reduce container is not running while inserting the data into external table

Comment: What place does elasticsearch have in what you are trying to do?

Comment: In the GCP, created a cluster Linux instance-2 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u5 (2019-08-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux to run elasticsearch

Comment: I used set hive.execution.engine=tez for that

Comment: Hi, I tried using with hive.execution.engine=mr(mapreduce) as well and still getting some errors

Comment: well it sure looks like your job is trying to write to ES index, and fails to find a running ES instance. As for your map vs. reduce question, no reduce phase in required for a simple copy operation thats why there is no reducers.

Comment: Then, how do i create index in the elasticssearch. this the error i'm getting while using the mapreduce engine. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/trying-to-insert-data-into-the-external-table/197368

Answer (score 4):

Try to add the following parameters before your request:

```
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled=false;
```

Comment: What are they for?